# How can I catch a unique constraint violation through QT's QSqlDatabase interface?

Tags: c++, sqlite, qt

The title says it all, really. I have a QT application, using the QSqlDatabase interface, and I need to take a different action on a unique key constraint violation as opposed to any other type of error.

Currently the backend database is SQLite, if that matters. However, management is talking about switching to MS SQL Server, so if the solution is database-specific, I'll need one for both.

Comment: You may have to parse the returned error message. And yes I would expect that each database type will have a different format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`QSqlQuery::lastError`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsqlquery.html#lastError) method to check an error occured while `INSERT` or `UPDATE` query execution. It returns QSqlError, which has a [`nativeErrorCode`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsqlerror.html#nativeErrorCode) method. I'm not sure, if it contains only a numeric value or a full error description.

In common, according to documentation SQLite should return [`2067`](https://www.sqlite.org/rescode.html#constraint_unique) error, however SQL  Server has a different error codes [`2601` and `2627`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/database-engine-events-and-errors?view=sql-server-ver16#errors-2000-to-2999), those are table key constraint specific.

So, you should check, if the string value of `QSqlError::nativeErrorCode` contains a database engine specific error code.

Comment: It turns out that SQLite returns [code "19"](https://www.sqlite.org/rescode.html#constraint) for duplicate unique keys. Thanks for the help!